# How do you initialize an array with "new" on a separate line?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm reading a book on C++. And I figured I should practice a little of what I know. So I created a class, and it contained a member in the form of `classname * name[]` which I would allocate later with `new` because I didn't know the amount of space it would need. So when I tried to type `name = new classname[capacity /* a variable passed in constructor */]`, it didn't work. Now that I think of it, this makes sense. I referred to my book, and I realized that `name` is the same thing as `&name[0]`. This explains why my IDE said "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". So now my question is, how can I declare an array on one line, and assign it with `new` on another line? I would also like to know why `type * name[]` is valid as a class member, but not outside of a class?

```
class MenuItem
{
public:
    MenuItem(string description):itsDescription(description) {};
    void setDescription(string newDescription);
    string getDescription() const;
private:
    string itsDescription;
};

void MenuItem::setDescription(string newDescription)
{
    itsDescription = newDescription;
}

string MenuItem::getDescription() const
{
    return itsDescription;
}

class Menu
{
public:
    Menu(int capacity);
private:
    MenuItem * items[];
};

Menu::Menu(int capacity)
{
    items = new MenuItem("")[capacity];
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Java, `MenuItem* items[]` is not a proper type, and is only allowed in three situations, and you aren't using it for any of those situations. Judging by the rest of your question, I assume you want a dynamically sized array of `MenuItem` items. In that case, your member should simply be `MenuItem* items;`. Then you can allocate an array of that object no problem.

```
int capacity = 4;
items = new MenuItem[capacity]; //these are default initialized
```

As the comments (and downvoters?) say, the "best" solution is simply to use a `std::vector<MenuItem> items` member instead, and let it automagically take care of the allocation and deallocation for you.

**Educational but not really important:**
The only times in C++ when you can have empty brackets `[]` are:

```
// as array parameters (don't be fooled, this is actually a pointer)
void myfunction(int array[])
```

and

```
// as local array defintion BUT ONLY WHEN IMMEDIATELY ASSIGNED VALUES
int array[] = {3, 6, 1};
```

and

```
// as the last member of an extensible object, for a C hack.

struct wierd {
    int array[];  // effectively a zero length array
};
wierd* dynamic = malloc(sizeof(wierd) + capacity*sizeof(int));

// don't do this in C++
// Actually, I think this is technically illegal as well, 
// but several compilers allow it anyway.
```

Comment: Vector is the method of choice for C++ I would think, though your way doesn't require STL.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I've now mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: +1.  Factually correct.  I learned to never answer array questions years ago.  No matter if what you say is useful, somebody will always be there to downvote it.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Yes, mentioning that is worthwhile, but answering a question like this with "use a vector" is not helpful. Arrays are not depricated and are still needed.  Everyone writing C++ code should understand how they work.  Hell, when VS 2005 shipped they enabled checked iterators and bounds checking *by default*, which slowed our image processing code down by 25%, so now... we use arrays (well, actually our own homegrown `vector` type) because it just isn't worth it should that pop up again. +1

Comment: To cast your doubts away, yes, that last thing is technically illegal.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an array is referenced by the address of its first element.  You'll notice that a pointer references an address...

```
MenuItem * items;
items = new MenuItem[size];
```

In this case items is a pointer to one or more MenuItem instances.  C++ is the same in this case.  This is a simplified version, there are other complexities to consider if you want to pass pointers to arrays as parameters, but I'm sure you'll figure those out when you get there.

Just in case you're wondering, with the code you had:

```
MenuItem * itemsarr[];   // invalid still because no array size
```

In this case you're declaring itemsarr as an array of pointers to MenuItem instances.  As the pendantic comment below indicated, this in itself is still not generally valid syntax unless you specify a legitimate array size, eg.

```
MenuItem * itemsarr[20];  // would be valid
```

**EDIT:** Made pedant-friendly.

Comment: "C++ is the same." Accurate _in this case_, but misleading, as in C++, you can get a reference to an array itself.  "you're declaring itemsarr as an array of pointers to MenuItem instances", that's not a valid C++ declaration, except as the last member of a struct.

Comment: He's obviously a beginner, I was trying to leave an understandable answer without getting into the confusing details.